# What is the trade term for the thing that connects the top of a load center panel to 2" EMT conduit?

Tags: electrical-panel, conduit

- What is the trade name for the "adapter" for the top conduit hole that is covered at the top of this picture that would allow you to connect 2" EMT conduit?
- It needs to be rain tight (3R).

(The picture is an Eaton NEMA 3R BRP20B200R)

[image: Load Center]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is a bit of a vexing problem, but a bolted hub with a raintight EMT compression fitting in it *should* work

NoSparksPlease is correct that the normal fitting for connecting conduit to the top of a rainproof (NEMA 3R) cabinet (panel enclosure) is a *bolted hub* attached to a mating point on the cabinet (in your case, an Eaton DS200H2, given that you have a recent Eaton panel).  However, hub fittings (both bolted and threaded/sealing) are designed to accept the tapered threads of a conduit, not the straight threads of an ordinary-location EMT (or flex, or AC/MC/NM) connector.  This creates a potential issue with both watertightness and bonding/grounding path continuity, as well as being outside the scope of the UL listing standards for both the hub and fitting.

Worse yet, while made-for-purpose EMT-to-rigid transition fittings exist, they are a) not generally available in 2" (Appleton makes the ETR-200, but it's not cheap) and b) worse yet, *not rated for wet locations*, ruling them out in an application like yours.  Furthermore, using a box or body to try to transition between conduit types simply moves the problem since the box or body will need to have a hub on it anyway.

The good news is that current *raintight* EMT fittings use a NPT (tapered) thread, as per [this IAEI Magazine article](https://iaeimagazine.org/features/transitioning-between-raceways/) and [the drawings for a Garvin CCNR-200](https://garvinindustries.com/pub/media/erp_files/images/Item%20Blueprints/ds-ccnr-200.pdf).  This means that the threads on the hub should accept a raintight EMT fitting acceptably for most AHJs.  (I could see a persnickity one requiring manufacturer drawings for the EMT fitting use that explicitly call out NPT threading.)

Answer (score 5):

A Raintight hub, that panel uses a [ds200h2](https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Meters-Accessories-Hub-Covers-Adaptors/Eaton/DS200H2/product.aspx?zpid=10715).

Comment: Assuming you mean RMC or IMC threaded pipe, the NEC doesn't recognize an EMC type conduit. EMT is a non-threaded type that would  require a "raintight connecter" to fit into a female hub. Some manufacturers of plastic pipe fittings call a male connector a "terminal adapter".

Comment: Add your comment to the answer itself - that appears to be some vital info. Not everyone reads comments, and as short as the answer is, while complete, it could get flagged for "low quality". Adding the comment to the answer will, at least, prevent that...

Comment: Note that there is a bit of debate as to whether the use of EMT connectors in bolted or Myers hubs is within Code (the issue has to do with straight vs. tapered threads and electrical grounding paths)

Comment: @NoSparksPlease, thanks I meant EMT and updated the post.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, do you have a reference or article about compression EMT connectors in female hubs? I posted a more targeted question here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/223540/how-do-you-correcly-use-emt-conduit-terminated-into-a-female-threaded-raintight

Comment: @KJ7LNW -- I'm posting an answer to this question that explains it