# How do you correctly use EMT conduit terminated into a female-threaded raintight hub atop a 3R outdoor panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, conduit

What is an NEC-accepted way of using EMT pipe with this female-threaded hub?

(The picture is an Eaton DS200H2 2" Rainproof Hub/Conduit/Plate to be used atop of a Eaton NEMA 3R BRP20B200R.)

[image: female threaded raintight hub]

Comment: Should be able to find a threaded EMT Raintight connector.  P.S. remember to "Think BIG" on panel number of breaker spaces.  Nobody in history ever said "My panel has loads of unused spaces, how can I add this new breaker to my panel?"

Comment: Are you coming straight down or from the side? 
Coming straight down something like a Hubble 298rt 2” rain tight compression connector will work. 
From the side it depends on the space you have to work with using a conduit body and nipple or a 90deg sweep are methods you can use, with EMT. There are probably as many ways to do this as there are electricians on this site. More information would be needed to be sure.

Comment: @EdBeal, Strait down into the BRP20B200R

Comment: See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/223542/125972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment I put 298rt it should be 2908rt I have used these with hubs in the past and passed inspection the lock nut is removed and the seal is left in place, the ones with straight threads seal on the ring the ones with tapered threads don’t make it to the ring but some of my inspectors will flag one without the ring.

although uncommon I have  used Myers hubs to emt connectors and after the inspector understood that I was adding the Myers hub for strength because of a TKO box he even allowed that (these will pull the tkos out over time with vibration).
This is where my experience in this matter is from I do not use emt for this in most cases I use rigid.

There is no other way to connect emt to a hub or coupling that I know of.

Comment: Yeah, not at this size in a wet location, at least -- in a dry place, or for smaller EMT (1" or less), one can use a EMT-to-RMC transition fitting and a RMC nipple instead, but nobody  I know of makes wet location EMT-to-RMC fittings

Comment: @threephaseeel as I said I have used that on Myers hubs and always passed  I would verify with the inspector but a hub is a hub. I can see it not passing if it’s for a mast them rigid is usually required.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, Ed: are the 2908rt and the Garvin CCNR-200 basically the same, or would you choose one over the other?

Comment: I just gave the part number for the one I stock. I would go with the least expensive, if same price go with the one that has a nut of a different color they both should be stamped wet location but the blue/green nut the inspector can see at a distance.